# Execution Reverted : Burn token and redeem ethers

Tags: solidity, erc-20, payable, burn

I'm developing two contracts:

**Tokens** :
*ERC20Burnable Transparent Upgradeable Proxy* - contract minting a token 1:1 for each ethers sent.

**Machine** :
*Transparent Upgradeable Proxy* - contract accepting Tokens as payment.
When Tokens are received, Machine instantly burn them and redeem the associated ethers.

---

So far, so good... Except that I keep getting reverted transaction when trying to burn and redeem.

Here is the `buy` function from **Machine** contract :

```
function buy(uint _amount) public {
    ITokens(tokensContract).burnAndRedeemFrom(
        _msgSender(),
        _amount
    );

    emit MachineBuy(_amount, _msgSender());
}
```

Here is the `burnAndRedeemFrom` function from **Tokens** contract :

```
function burnAndRedeemFrom(address _from, uint _amount) public {
    burnFrom(_from, _amount);

    payable(_msgSender()).transfer(_amount);

    emit TokensBurn(_amount);
}
```

I'm sure that **Tokens** contract has funds.
I'm sure that allowance from the address to **Machine** contract is correct.

Still I keep getting execution reverted?

How are transactions working here? Should the `buy` function be payable so the **Tokens** contract can send ethers?

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `buy` doesn't need to be `payable`. Who will receive the Redeemed ether ?  the Machine contract or the user who calls  `buy` function from Machine contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a guess here, will update if I get more info. I assume you have carefully checked others condition (e.g. approval & ether balance). The revert may come from this :

```
  payable(_msgSender()).transfer(_amount);
```

Here `_msgSender()` is the `Machine` contract. If that contract doesn't implement `receive payable` or `fallback payable` it will reject ether and revert the whole tx.
This could be what you want to implement, the redeemed Ether will be sent directly to the user who triggers the transaction (who has the token).

```
  payable(_from).transfer(_amount);
```

Comment: You are right, it works perfectly when an user owned address calls `burnAndRedeemFrom`, but a contract calling this function would need a `receive() external payable` fallback function.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *@minhhn2910* I understood that my **Machine** contract was missing a fallback *payable* function!

So I added this to my **Machine** contract and now it works perfectly :

```
receive() external payable {}
```

More informations about fallback and receive functions here :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMVC6Tp9gq4